# Water shutoff valve from wall not dispensing any water when hooking up a new fridge to a new house. Water flows fine in all other places in house

Tags: water, refrigerator, valve, shutoff

Water shutoff valve from wall not dispensing any water when hooking up a new fridge to a new house. Water flows fine in all other places in house. How can I get water to flow to my new fridge?

Comment: Welcome! Some more info on your issue would be help us out here. Was the shutoff newly installed for the fridge install? Did it ever work correctly? If you remove any attached hose, can water flow directly out of the shutoff? A photo of the valve itself would be useful, or at least info such as valve type (quarter turn or multi-turn), how long it has been there, etc.

Comment: Would guess it has a blockage in it, but usually would get some water, even just drips, or it is not hooked up to the house plumbing.  Might also be another valve before it that is not turned on/opened.

Comment: A new fridge will often have a temporary plastic plug in the water inlet to keep out debris.